# PostUpdateEventListener not being called

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to implement some logic where on one entity update I need to update a field on another entity. I would like to do that in post update listener. 
I have my code setup as below, however my `onPostUpdate` handler isn't getting called. What am I doing wrong ?
In my test code I am calling `documentRepository.save(documentEntity)`.

( I have tried the same approach with POST_INSERT and PostInsertEventListener, and that worked just fine. My handler was called)

```
@Component
public class DocumentUpdateListener implements PostUpdateEventListener {

    @Override
    public void onPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent event) {

        ... //some business logic here
    }


    @Override
    public boolean requiresPostCommitHanding(EntityPersister persister) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean requiresPostCommitHandling(EntityPersister persister) {
        return true;
    }
}

@Component
public class EntityEventListenerRegistry {

    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Autowired
    private DocumentUpdateListener documentUpdateListener;

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory = emf.unwrap(SessionFactoryImpl.class);
        EventListenerRegistry registry = sessionFactory.getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_UPDATE).appendListener(documentUpdateListener);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. In my test, I had to run `entityManager.flush()`, after that all is being called as expected. It's odd though that I didn't need to do that for `POST_INSERT` though